# Test scenarios for testing of touch screen driver

Tags: manual-testing

I am supposed to test a touch screen driver using black box method.
What kind of scenarios should I consider?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Are you really testing a touch screen driver (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) or are you testing a touchscreen application? What is the usage of the application or driver?

Comment: I have a touch screen monitor. Touch events are recognized through USB using a driver. I need to test the driver.

Comment: Do you have a tool that reads the events passed through the driver? Without that, you don't have a black box, you have a black hole (that is, stuff goes in and nothing comes out). You need the output as well as the input for black box tests.

Answer (score 2):

What type of touchscreen- Resistive or capacitive ?

Here are some of the things I tested when I was in charge of testing a similar driver:

- sanity- draw some predefined shapes and compare to the actual results. Choose simple and complex shapes, letters etc.
- accuracy- touch the screen and compare to the coordinates you expect as reported by the driver. Make sure to include the edges, corners and center.
- accuracy over time- swipe your finger (or stylus) very slowly across the screen, make sure the lines stay straight
- stability- draw a shape on the screen repeatedly for long duration.
- stability- touch the screen in predefined locations (same as accuracy, but in less locations), repeat
- reboot your device and make sure the driver is properly loaded (e.g. run the sanity test above)
- resistive screen reports the strength of the touch, add this to the tests above
- capacitive screens may still function with the finger above screen, add this to the tests above ("hovering")

The above tests checked the "lower" half of the driver, use the real application to test how the driver reports results to the OS.